# Krusader export settings

Tags: kde, krusader

Is it possible to export settings in KDE 4 Krusader with keybindings, colors and so on? How?

I think about just copy ~/.kde/share/apps/krusader, but dont see color scheme settings there.

Answer (score 3):

**KDE configuration settings**

The KDE and KDE application settings are saved to the `~/.kde/share/config/`. Krusader settings are saved to the `~/.kde/share/config/krusaderrc`.

The Krusader also has Import/Export color-scheme:

[image: Screenshot of crusader configuration UI]

Comment: I understood with the color scheme, but what about other settings, which file I need to be able to restore the same setting on another machine?

Comment: Krusader settings are saved to the ~/.kde/share/config/krusaderrc. If you copy it then you are copying all Krusader settings.

Answer (score 1):

In the current version (2.8.0 “A New Day”) -  and maybe some older ones - the configuration file is

```
                                ~/.config/krusaderrc
```

From [The Krusader Handbook](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/krusader/krusader/index.html), [Appendix A. Configuration Files](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/krusader/krusader/config_files.html):

> This file stores the Krusader configuration.
>
> Location: `~/.config/krusaderrc`
>
> The following settings are e.g. stored:
>
> - Actions Toolbar
> - Archives
> - Colors
> - Dependencies
> - DiskUsage
> - DiskUsageViewer
> - General
> - HTML Settings
> - KFileDialog
> - KFileDialog Speedbar
> - KrDetailedViewLeft
> - KrDetailedViewRight
> - KrViewerWindow
> - KrViewerWindow Toolbar extraToolBar
> - Look & Feel
> - Notification Messages
> - Panel Profiles
> - Private
> - Protocols
> - Search
> - Startup
> - Synchronize
> - Locate
> - SynchronizerProfile - 1